# Undesirable Credits incurred due to querying system-defined SNOWFLAKE DB

Tags: tableau-api, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, usage-tracking

This is regarding the Tableau Snowflake usage monitoring report discussed in this link. https://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2019/5/monitor-understand-snowflake-account-usage?_ga=2.107754242.1833616758.1620049769-552039319.1616681733

I have a question. Are the queries running behind the dashboard likely to incur credits on Snowflake. I am using my project warehouse and role and therefore I think it is incurring credits, which is not desirable. It is like incurring new credits to track credit and usage via a elaborate multi-query dashboard when all data behind it really comes from system-defined databases and schema ( SNOWFLAKE DB and Account_Usage schema) that is storing account metadata .

Could you please let me know if this dashboard could be run free of cost using a generic user credential that is provided by snowflake that does not incur more credits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Snowflake database is an inbound share. Although the share is from Snowflake rather than a Snowflake customer, the same rules apply for using shared data on a full account (as opposed to a reader account). The account sharing the data pays for storage, and the account running queries pays for compute. So yes, there's a charge since you'll pay for the warehouse compute. You do not have to pay for storage unless you choose to copy some of the data shared from Snowflake. The most common reason to do that is to preserve query history longer than 1 year, which is the default.